# Cascading Spinner Not Wokring

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am new to android, I am trying to implement the cascading spinner. When I select the first spinner it should populate the second spinner choices based on the 1st spinner selection. I have almost done, but in second spinner I cannot select the value. When I select the value it is disappearing. Please help me in this.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DummyMain extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    public Spinner spinner1, spinner2;
    public String[] spinner1Values = {"A", "B"}, valuesForA = {"1", "2"}, valuesForB = {"3", "4", "5", "1"};
    public ArrayAdapter<String> adapterForSpinner1, adapterForSpinner2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dummy_main);

        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

        adapterForSpinner1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinner1Values);
        adapterForSpinner1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(adapterForSpinner1);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long l) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Result "+spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (parent.getId() == R.id.spinner1) {
            if (spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("A")) {
                adapterForSpinner2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,valuesForA);
                adapterForSpinner2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinner2.setAdapter(adapterForSpinner2);
                spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

            } else {
                adapterForSpinner2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,valuesForB);
                adapterForSpinner2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinner2.setAdapter(adapterForSpinner2);
                spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, I have fixed it.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterForSpinner2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, valuesForB);
```

I have changed the **getApplicationConetxt()** into **this**. It works :-)

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterForSpinner2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, valuesForB);
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding this in your DummyMain

```
@Override
    public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {
    }
```